# c++ unable to get proper string input

Tags: c++

I am new to programming just wrote this simple function to calculate length of a string but I am unable to take input string from the user properly(have tried my alternatives).

```
/////////Function to calculate length of a string////////////////////
void str_length(){
    char str[30];
    int counter=0;
    cout << "Enter string: ";
    gets(str);
    //cin.getline(str,256);
    //cin >> str;
    for(int i=0;str[i] != '\0';i++){
        counter++;
    }
    cout << "String length is: " << counter << endl;
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

of all possible ways the program either exits abruptly or with 'cin' I can only get partial string till the first space.

Comment: I am damn sure that before gets(str) statement, you are taking integer as an input using `scanf("%d",..)`, somewhere in your code or may be the fn that is calling str_length()

Comment: omg. std::string str; std::cin >> str; int length = str.length();

Comment: @maverik, It needs spaces. One statement has to be changed.

Comment: @Arslan Tariq: Can you plz paste the entire code.

Comment: @arslan, `gets` is one of the worst abominations to roam C and C++. Anyone who enters more than 29 characters will cause a buffer overflow and you will be powerless to stop it. Use `std::string`. It's perfectly safe and just as easy, as well as easier to use after.

Comment: std::string str; std::getline(std::cin, str); int length = str.length();

Comment: using char array is much faster than using str::string. **use str::string is a suggestion not a solution.**

Comment: Oh, and `gets` is not in the standard (both in C and C++) anymore.

Comment: @ritesh_nitw, no it's not.

Comment: @ritesh_nitw: But `std::string` is much safer and saner to use. Sure, you can drive to hell faster with a char array, like our grandparents did…

Comment: @DarkDust, you've made my day :D

Comment: I wonder why nobody is talking about fgets here even after so many comments. Within in C, fgets is the one that should be used to prevent buffer overflow

Comment: @DarkDust : I knw its a safer. Even fgets is another alternative. But the things that i want to mention is Op don't want alternative to gets, rather he wants to know the reason why using gets not working perfectly.

Comment: @bjskishore123, because question is tagged with C++ tag. Should we discuss C here?

Comment: @maverik I mentioned it as OP preferring to use C functions. And do you see the tag to determine language used or do you see the code written? :)

Comment: from the manpage of `gets`: **never use gets** - that's all there is to say.

Comment: OP uses std::cout, std::endl. It is C++, right? Anyway, it is a nice observation about fgets.

Comment: Also note that the null-termination is part of the string. You may be off by one.

Comment: @ritesh_nitw, I'd like to see proof of how `std::string` is so much slower than C strings that it shouldn't even be used for simple assignments. I bet it's not as slow as you think it is. There are optimizations like SSO that help as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you tried `cin.getline(str,256)`, you'd have needed your buffer to be declared as `char str[256]`.

You shouldn't really be involving yourself with these things however. Stick with `std::string`:

```
std::string str; // Declare a string
std::getline(std::cin, str); // Get a line from the std::cin stream and put it in str
unsigned int stringLength = str.length(); // get the length of the string
```

Comment: That's not a solution.**use str::string is a suggestion.**

Comment: Would you like me to add a solution without std::string? :o

Comment: Actually, when you see the question with C strings and `gets`, using `std::string` is the solution.

Comment: Question tagged with C++. Author didn't specify that he really needs only char arrays (because of the restriction, etc). The right answer is to use std::string.

Comment: That's what OP wants. Also The OP already mentioned that he is using gets(str) for taking input. So, your first line cin.getline(str,256) is irrelevant.

Comment: I was only pointing out what may have been a mistake in his previous attempt to get a line from the input stream. (The commented out code)

Comment: @ritesh_nitw there is no `gets` function in the standard C++ nor in the standard C: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/gets/, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision). The OP should not use something that is a) not portable b) not safe c) there are plenty of safe and portable function to achieve what OP asked.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use the `std::string` library. It is nice and easy to use.

```
void str_length()
{
   std::string line;
   std::cout << " Please input current line: " << std::endl;
   std::getline(std::cin, line);
   std::cout << "the length of input string is: " << line.length() <<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Don't you mean std::getline?

Answer (score 2):

I can only agree with my previous speakers and would recommend you to use the better variant by using `std::string`. Nevertheless if you really want to use C-String than you can use this approach:
`std::cin.get(char *s, streamsize n)`
This method reads in characters until you press the enter button.

```
#include<iostream>
#define SIZE 40;

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char str[SIZE];

    cin.get(str, SIZE-1);

    cout << str << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

You should be aware if you have once created an buffer overflow that you will get some trouble at the next call of this method. The problem is that your input buffer will save the remaining characters and at the next call your methods will only read in the remaining characters. To solve this problem you have to clear your input buffer before each input.

Best practice is to use this code in front of each `cin.get()`

```
while(cin.get() != '\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

void str_length(){
    char str[30];
    std::cout<< "Enter string: ";
    std::cin>>str;
    int counter=0;
    for(counter=0;str[counter] != '\0';counter++){}
    std::cout<<"String length is "<<counter<<std::endl;
}
```

OR

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void str_length(){
    std::string str;
    std::cout<<"Enter string: "<<std::endl;
    std::cin>>str;
    std::cout<<"String length is "<<str.size()<<endl;
}
```

Comment: the line might have spaces